# Вкладка Бюллетень в настройках не переведена

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Вкладка [Бюллетень](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/email/newsletters/current) в настройках не переведена:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кстати, на мете и основном сайте немного разные сообщения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теперь переведено:

> [image: Был бюллетень да сплыл]

Правда, с учётом тихого [появления нового редактора переводов](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=45228192#45228192), "бюллетень" неожиданно превратился в "новостную рассылку".

Comment: Уверен, что компромисс может быть найден, но путь, который выбран вами (язвительная отсылка к моему «тихому появлению»), едва ли приведет к чему-либо хорошему. Видимо, мне стоило спросить ваше мнение об этом пункте профиля, прежде чем утверждать изменения, — но, повторю, это не повод начинать травлю/войну.